# Wrong order for elements in RTL mode on Helix3

Tags: joomla-3.4, helix3

My website has 2 languages, English and Arabic. Arabic language is rtl (right to left). On my PC it works fine but when using mobile phone or resize the browser there is wrong order for elements (the left element at the top and the right element at bottom) look at numbers 1111111,22222222,33333333 and 44444444: http://food.yesrtl.com/index.php/ar/

- SP PAGE BUILDER Version 1.0.5

Comment: This is something you need to contact the developer about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting problem, because most templates will stack modules just like that, placing the left module at the top, which of course doesn't make sense for rtl languages.

This happens because the elements are set to `float:left`. My guess is that you've sorted your modules in the Joomla module manager in this order:

```
4444
3333
2222
1111
```

Try reversing the order (1-2-3-4), then add this code to your CSS file, **but only for the Arabic language**:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sppb-section .sppb-col-sm-3 {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Your modules should be properly displayed for all screen sizes.

Another option would be to create two sets of modules, one for horizontal display and another for vertical (mobile) display. Then use CSS and media queries to display/hide the modules as needed. Using Helix3, you can add module suffix `hidden-xs` to hide the module on mobiles, and `visible-xs` to show on mobiles only.

Comment: In addition to johanpw's solution you might be able to try a CSS only solution with media queries. Look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918693/reverse-the-order-of-divs-children and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425665/switching-the-order-of-block-elements-with-css to get you started.